# Getting a String or Int from the method to send it to another Activity

Tags: java, android

I am getting an ID from the server every time users enter the app and I need to send that ID to another activity because I do things based on that taken ID from the server. but I don't know how to get it from the Function to store it in a variable and then send it by intent. Here is my code Please guide me how to do it :

```
public class SuperAdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int ID = -1;
private String s;
private ProgressDialog loading;
private SharedPreferences sp;
private Button register_new_company, register_new_user, see_all_userslist, see_all_companies_list, new_item;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_super_admin);
    register_new_company = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register_new_company);
    register_new_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register_new_user);
    see_all_userslist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_all_users_list);
    see_all_companies_list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_all_organizations_list);
    new_item = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new_item);
    sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userP", 0);
    s = sp.getString("Username", "");
    Log.e("Username ", s);
    getData();
}
public void onRegisterButtonNewCompanyClicked(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterNewCompany.class));
}

public void onUserRegisterButtonClicked(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, UserRegisteration.class));

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
}


private void getData() {
    String id = s;
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Getting Some data...", false, false);

    String url = config.DATA_URL + s.toString().trim();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);

            Log.e("RESPONE : ", response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response) {
    String name = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = collegeData.getString("usr_type");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("UserType = ", name);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(name);
    ID = Integer.parseInt(name);
    Log.e("My Current ID :" , String.valueOf(ID));
    if (i == 1) {
        register_new_company.setEnabled(true);
        register_new_user.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        register_new_company.setEnabled(false);
        register_new_user.setEnabled(false);
    }

}

public void onBtnAllUsersListCLick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityAllUsers.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID",ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    //startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityAllUsers.class));
}
}
```

As you see I can access `getData();` function inside the `onCreate` and this method **Logs** the array it gets from the server side but I want to store the **int** which is in the **showJSON** method

Comment: post your json too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a global variable ID which is integer type like

```
int ID = -1;// -1 is default value
```

and then assign value in your showJSON Method

like

```
ID = //get value from json which is received from server
```

and then pass it to any activity like this

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(SuperAdminActivity.this, UserRegisteration.class);
          intent.putExtra("ID", ID)
          startActivity(intent);
```

Get ID in `UserRegisteration` like

```
int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID", -1);// -1 is default value
```

Comment: I did what you said but I can't get the **ID** in other activity.
I printed the **ID** by **Log** in other Activity but it Logs **-1**.
Here `ID = Integer.parseInt(name);` I assigned **i** to **ID** and  I logged and it showed the **ID** correctly but when I get it in other activity it is -1

Comment: @Shayea ID = Integer.parseInt(name);  can you print this and let me know what is the log?

Comment: Here is its Log : `03-15 07:32:54.101 8205-8205/com.sof.soflogisticcompany E/My Current ID :: 4`

Comment: can you post your entire activity code [http://pastebin.com/] so i can get idea about it?

Comment: @Shayea Yes, you are correct but how can i let you know without what else you did, so please paste so i can help you further.

Comment: I edited the question and added all the Activity codes including your edits you said

Comment: @Shayea Do one more trick pass one more value like `intent.putExtra("name", "Shayea");` and get in next activity like `String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");` Now let me know are you getting name?

Comment: It Logs correctly when I log `Log.e("NAMEEEEEEEEEEE : " , name);
` , Here is the log : `E/NAMEEEEEEEEEEE :: Shayea`

Comment: Solved the problem bro , It was my mistake I had a space when getting the ID

Comment: @Shayea Please accept my answer and don't forget to subscribe my youtube channel for more updates on android & iOS **https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ**

Answer (score 1):

You can Passing data: Direct Using Intent like below:

Intent has several method called `putExtra(String name, …..)` that allows us to save inside the Intent our information. Reading the API Doc we know that we can add string, longs, `CharSequence`, int and so on.It behaves like a Map where there’s the key and the value. In the caller `(EditActivity)` we can pass data in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EditActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
intent .putExtra("name", edtName.getText().toString();
intent .putExtra("surname", edtSurname.getText().toString();
intent .putExtra("email", edtEmail.getText().toString();
startActivity(i);
```

And you can retrive all this data in next activity like bwlow :

Where “name”, “surname” and “email” are the keys. In other word first we create the intent (line 1) defining the caller activity (EditActivity) and the destination activity (ViewActivity), then we use putExtra to add our data. In the destination activity to retrieve the data sent we have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Intent intent  = getIntent();

String name = intent .getStringExtra("name"));
String surname = intent .getStringExtra("surname"));
String email = intent .getStringExtra("email"));
. . .
}
```

please find more details in below link:
[Passing data between activities](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/passing-data-between-activities-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Make a global variable in your activity like `int number` as you made `String s`. in your `showJSON` where you are getting `int i = Integer.parseInt(name);` assigin this `i` to your global `int number` like `number = i;` and on every button click you can pass this number within intent. like

```
intent.putExtra("key", number);
```

Comment: I did what you said but I can't get the **ID** in other activity.
I printed the **ID** by **Log** in other Activity but it Logs **-1**.
Here `ID = Integer.parseInt(name);` I assigned **i** to **ID** and  I logged and it showed the **ID** correctly but when I get it in other activity it is -1

Comment: there is a chance, you need to make sure that `onResponse` has received some response and id have been populated before moving to new activity as there is chance you click button to go to next activity and your server respond later. to check, just wait a while until your response log prints and then click next activity.

Comment: of course I receive the JSON in `onResponse`, here is the Log : `03-15 07:32:54.101 8205-8205/com.sof.soflogisticcompany E/RESPONE :: {"result":[{"usr_type":"4"}]}
`

Comment: make sure you are only moving to next activity once you have received response. is this so?

Comment: Yes I did what you say , you can see the I edited the question and added all the codes

Comment: yes I have seen, can you show how are receiving it in `ActivityAllUsers`?

Comment: also inside `onBtnAllUsersListCLick` method before putting ID into intent, log and check what is being added in intent.

Comment: Here is what I did in `ActivityAllUsers` : `int id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID ", -1);// -1 is default value` and here when I log it shows **-1** `Log.e("ID  : = " , String.valueOf(id));`

Comment: It Logs the correct **ID** when I Log in `onBtnAllUsersListCLick `

Comment: see "ID " in `getIntExtra("ID ", -1)`, change it to "ID"

Comment: Thanks bro it was my bad, Thank you